# OutOfMemoryError: Using a image which is 1080*1920 do the splash page

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

I want to implement a splash page in my android app. So in the layout xml, there is a imageView and the image file is a png file which is `1080*1920`, when a run the app, it occur a `OutOfMemoryError` error, how can I fix that?

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/welcome1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error info:

```
04-17 18:40:16.038  29793-29793/cn.test.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cn.test.android, PID: 29793
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:597)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:432)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
        at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2477)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2136)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:320)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
        at cn.test.android.LandingPageActivity$1.instantiateItem(LandingPageActivity.java:40)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:987)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1946)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1325)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1030)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5639)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is why you better use a **tiled** bitmap (much smaller) With some text overlayed.

Comment: Use low resolution image or programmatically decode it using `BitmapFactory.Options`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have `welcome1.png` in the `drawable` folder, put it in the `drawable-nodpi`.

This is because `drawable` is interpreted as `drawable-mdpi`, so when you load it on a higher density phone it will be upscaled (becoming a gigantic bitmap).

Answer (score 2):

memory allocated to per App is sparse in android you should not be giving it to images just like that.

your application is running low on memory due to which you are getting this error.

```
what you can do is increase cahce memory of emulator to support your memory usage.
```

well that's not the exact solution, try minimizing image resolution and you can get rid of this error,

Answer (score 2):

Android in general has problems with images, especially large ones. This is due to the maximum amount an App is allowed to allocate. You can resample bitmaps as you load them in.

As a short example, this will reduce the size of the image by half:

```
final BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to scale down your original image (keeping the aspect ratio) and than set the `scaleType` in your `ImageView` ro *fitCenter* or *centerCrop*:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
    android:background="@drawable/welcome1"/>
```